# Cannot get Magento 2 catalog price incl tax to work

Tags: magento2, price, tax, vat

I have a problem with Magento 2, I have configured a tax class and settings for including it in catalog and entered price in admin. Still when I get `priceinfo` I get this price:

For a product of price 119:

```
$prices = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrices();
var_dump($prices->current()->getAmount());

Outputs:

object(Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base)[2082]
   protected 'amount' => float 148.75
   protected 'baseAmount' => null
   protected 'totalAdjustmentAmount' => null
   protected 'adjustmentAmounts' => 
     array (size=1)
       'tax' => float 29.750001
   protected 'adjustments' => 
     array (size=0)
       empty
```

Why is magento adding the tax on top of 119 despite my settings?

I have done some further research in this, it seems magento2 has a problem counting taxes backwards?

When running `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data` function `getTaxPrice` I set price at 119 to include tax and to return price without tax:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Helper/Data.php#L515

Should not this function return 119 * 0.8 = 95.2 in this case? As my tax is 25% and backwards tax that is 20%.

I run the function as this:

```
$catalogHelper->getTaxPrice($product, $product->getPrice(), false, null,null,null,null,true,true)
```

It returns 119 to me which seems weird.

Comment: Thank you! I looked for the answer, but have found only your question and it was helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

My solution for base prices incl. vat is

```
$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

For special price it will be

```
$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

Comment: This works for simples, but configurables still show me the price excl.

Comment: Hi, can you please let me know the admin settings to display including tax product price in custom module? Because I can't get incl. tax price for simple products using your solution. It would be great to help me.

Answer (score 1):

So i had missed the setting for the store location which messed it up. *facepalm*